# Book with the Latin quote 'nihil superbus' meaning 'nothing above us'

Tags: story-identification, novel

I know it's very little to go on, but I've had the Latin phrase *nihil superbus, meaning 'nothing above us'* knocking around my head for a while now but can't place it.

It appears in some book within the context of an extract from a (fictional) old text (possibly Biblical/fake-Biblical) at the end of the passage, with an English translation given (though that might have been in archaic English). I think it was used as an epigraph, or epigraphically at the end of the story.

*I'm aware that this isn't an accurate translation but I feel like that was what was given.

Comment: "*Nihil superbus*" actually means "nothing arrogant."  "Nothing above us" would be "*Nihil super nobis*."

Comment: This is off-topic if there weren’t any science fiction or fantasy elements in the book.

Comment: Flagged for reopening; the OP has confirmed the answer is from HPMOR which **is** on-topic.

Comment: @Stormblessed, the OP has confirmed this is HPMOR, and therefore on-topic.

Comment: @Stormblessed Apologies for not saying it in the original post, but I was pretty certain it was fantasty or sci-fi, otherwise I wouldn't have posted it here!

Comment: @dbmag9 okay; you'd be surprised how many very clearly off-topic story-IDs we get here

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are missremembering it a bit, you could be thinking of [Harry Potter and the Methods of Rationality](https://www.hpmor.com/chapter/75).

From Godric Griffindor's short autobiography is the following quote:

> Non est salvatori salvator,
>   neque defensori dominus,
>   nec pater nec mater,
>   nihil supernum.
>   
>   - Godric Gryffindor,
>   1202 C.E.

Translated to:

> No rescuer hath the rescuer, 
>   no Lord hath the champion, 
>   no mother and no father, 
>   only nothingness above.

The English is actually given during the main part of the page with the original text at the end.

Comment: The key phrase also appears on the Sword of Gryffindor, and is mistranslated by Harry as "nothing better".

Comment: This was it – I was sure it was a book (I was thinking in a Pullman/Gaiman sort of direction) so don't think it would have occurred to me otherwise. Thank you!